# How i can group array based on values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array

```
array1 = [{
    category: "Age"
    id: "11"
  },
  {
    category: "Gender"
    id: "M"
  },
  {
    category: "Age"
    id: "23"
  },
  {
    category: "Gender"
    id: "F"
  },
  {
    category: "Education"
    id: "Graduate"
  },
  {
    category: "Age"
    id: "55"
  }
]
```

I want this to group by category, something like this

```
groupedArray = [{
  category: "Age",
  groupedCat: [{
      category: "Age"
      id: "11"
    },
    {
      category: "Age"
      id: "23"
    },
    {
      category: "Age"
      id: "55"
    }
  ],
  category: "Gender",
  groupedCat: [{
      category: "Gender"
      id: "M"
    },
    {
      category: "Gender"
      id: "F"
    }
  ],
  category: "Education",
  groupedCat: [{
    category: "Education"
    id: "Graduate"
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Please add the code that you've tried and share what's not working.

Comment: Please search before you ask. The dupe is very clear. Also, please try to read the [ask] page and ask next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```js
var array1 = [{
  category: "Age",
  id: "11"
}, {
  category: "Gender",
  id: "M"
}, {
  category: "Age",
  id: "23"
}, {
  category: "Gender",
  id: "F"
}, {
  category: "Education",
  id: "Graduate"
}, {
  category: "Age",
  id: "55"
}];

let res = {};
for (var o of array1) {
  if (res[o.category] === undefined) {
    res[o.category] = [];
  }
  res[o.category].push(o);
}
console.log(res);
```

Note that this is not exactly as you wanted from your question above, I instead used the `category` as the key for the object. I assume this is what you're looking for. If not leave a comment and I could update.

Hope this helps,